# Background opacity not being rendered

Tags: css, sass

I have this strange problem that, actually, I've never seen before.

There is a main wrapper with an opacity that hold a modal with a white background. The wrapper has a `background-color` setted with as following:

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);`

The strage thing is on how it get rendered in two pcs.

Here's what it looks like on my pc:

[image]

Here's what it looks like on a netbook:

[image]

What I've noticed is that the netbook is in power energy save mode, but I don't really know if this can cause this problem. I've tried this application in others pc but it works fine.

What could possibly be?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd try to see first if other style and/or script are executed in the netbook (e.g. css on specific mediaqueries or scripts dependent on the viewport size). If you switch off the power energy save mode does the problem solve? Does this happen in that laptop only?

Comment: I've checked and the scripts and styles applied are the same. I've tried turning off the power energy save mode but still nothing. Just this laptop is doing this. I tought it could be a problem caused to the bad graphic card installed. Does this makes sense to you?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Can you tell me if [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RdjvKW) is rendering correctly?

Comment: On my pc is fine. On the small one, instead, is none. But I've managed to solve it by using opacity instead of the rgba. But this makes no-sense at all. Why a standard rgba is not working properly? That's strange.

Comment: What browser are you using on the netbook?

Comment: The same Chrome version, the latest.